# Add event listener to Titanium

Tags: javascript, dom-events, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I'm new to  Titanium and Web programming and Mobile apps. I want to make simple event listener. When I click the image another window opens. The other windows must be an external .js file

```
var image=Ti.UI.createImageWiew({
image:'...............',
 })


image.addeventListener('click',function(){

//what do I write here?

 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this code inside your listener:

```
image.addeventListener('click',function(){
    var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
         url:'external.js' 
    });   
    Ti.UI.currentTab.open(window,{animated:true});

});
```

And write this code inside your external.js file:

```
var window = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
window.backgroundImage = 'your-bg-image';
```

If you are opening a window using url, you can't do this:

```
var win=Ti.UI.createWindow({ });
```

inside your js file.

Comment: thank you so much. I have a problem.my external.js what it include I write this   var win=Ti.UI.createWindow({  backgroundImage:'   ' })   it cannot open new windows.

Comment: I want simple thing my external.js file shows only bakcground image

Answer (score 0):

```
var wndMyWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
     url             : 'ExternalFile.js',
     backgroundImage : 'mybackgroundImage.png'
}); 

wndMyWindow.open();
```

The above code will open a new window, here you're telling the background image before opening the window.

If you want you can tell this after opening the window as follows

**ExternalFile.js**

```
var wndMyWindow = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
wndMyWindow.backgroundImage = 'mybackgroundImage.png';//This will also set background image for your window
```

You can add other controls to this window if you want. You can add those controls like

`wndMyWindow.add(yourControl);`

Read [this](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium) link also. It will help you to understand commonJS module which helps to work with different files.

Happy programming:)